# How can I get this specific data format into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file which is in this format

```
====================
Something Something Something
====================
Something Something Something
====================
Something Something Something
====================
Something Something Something
Something Something Something
Something Something Something
====================
Something Something Something

Something Something Something
Something Something Something
====================
Something Something Something
====================
Something Something Something
====================
Something Something Something
====================
```

As I am trying to illustrate, there are some newline, some empty lines but the defining feature is that the content i am trying to capture is always between lines of equals signs.

I have tried .read_csv but this does not work, because the value of the cells in the dataframes should display all text, including the newlines.

Specifically,

```
df = pd.read_csv(x + "/" + file, sep="====================", names=["Content"], engine="python", index_col=False)
```

My desired dataframe then looks like

```
   Content
0     Something Something Something
1     Something Something Something\n                 \nSomething Something Something\nSomething Something Something
```

For example.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

First define a custom file reader class:

```
class InFile:
    def __init__(self, infile):
        self.infile = open(infile)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = ''
        while True:
            line = self.infile.readline()
            if not line:
                self.infile.close()
                return line
            if line[:4] == '====':
                if len(res) > 0:
                    break
            else:
                res += line
        return res
```

Then convert your input file into a list of strings (some of them are
multi-line strings):

```
ff = InFile('Input.txt')
tbl = []
while True:
    tt = ff.read()
    if not tt: break
    tbl.append(tt.strip())
```

And the last step is to create a DataFrame from this list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Content': tbl})
```

Unfortunately, if you attempt just to `print(df)`, *Pandas* prints this
DataFrame with the **textual representation** of each `\n`,
and the whole (possibly multi-line) string takes a **single** row anyway.

So a better method to check what has been read is to run a custom loop,
printing the index and *Content* field from each row:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    print(f'  Idx: {idx}')
    print(row.Content)
```

For your data sample, with a consecutive number inserted after each
*Something*, the result is:

```
  Idx: 0
Something1 Something Something
  Idx: 1
Something2 Something Something
  Idx: 2
Something3 Something Something
  Idx: 3
Something4 Something Something
Something5 Something Something
Something6 Something Something
  Idx: 4
Something7 Something Something

Something8 Something Something
Something9 Something Something
  Idx: 5
Something10 Something Something
  Idx: 6
Something11 Something Something
  Idx: 7
Something12 Something Something
```

Note that after *Something7* the output contains an empty line, just like
in your input file.